# Queue with fair dequeing from multiple producer keys

Tags: java, concurrency, deque, concurrenthashmap, lifo

I have this scenario where I am receiving events from thousands of sources. Each source is sending information about its current status. While I do want to process all events, it is more important to first process the latest event of each source, so that the current view is up to date. So I was thinking of using a [`ConcurrentHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) with the identifier of each source as the key, and a LIFO queue (stack) as the value. I would then iterate through the keys of the `Map` and just pop one item off the stack of each source.

My concern is that while I am iterating through the keys and taking items off the queue of each key, the producer could post new events on the queues, potentially creating concurrency issues. The producer could also add new keys to the map, and iterating through the [`entrySet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#entrySet--) of the `Map` seems to be weakly consistent. Which is not a huge issue, because the new item will be processed in a subsequent iteration. Ideally I could also use some parallel processing on the stream of the `entrySet` to speed up the process.

I am wondering if there is a cleaner approach to this. In reality I could have used a LIFO [`BlockingDequeue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingDeque.html) and processed latest events first, but the problem with this approach is that there is a risk that one source could send more events than others and thus maybe get more events processed than the others.

Is there any other data structure that I could look into that provides this kind of behaviour? Essentially what I am looking for is a way to prioritise events from each source, while at the same time giving a fair chance to each source to be processed by the consumer.

Answer (score 0):

Did you think about a FIFO queue of LIFO queues? Each source adds to its LIFO queue and for processing you take the first LIFO queue from the FIFO queue, process one event and then put it back into the FIFO queue. This way you also should have no problem with new sources, as their LIFO queue will simply be added to the FIFO queue.

For adding events to the correct LIFO queue, you can maintain an additional HashMap that knows the queue per source and if a new source occurs that is not in the Map yet, you know you have to add its LIFO queue to the FIFO queue.

Comment: This is interesting. However, the issue is that we would need to be able to add new events to the Stack (LIFO queues) as they come in for the specific source, which means we would need to find the respective Stack in the Queue. I think I might be able to solve this with an extra `ConcurrentHashMap<String, Stack>` mapping the key of the source to the LIFO queue of the source.

Comment: Yes, if the source does not know where to put the events to, a HashMap should do.

Comment: Yeah, so what I am looking to build is a datastructure that looks like a Queue from the outside, just adding and removing, but internally it is doing this logic of prioritising accordingly. I will try your suggestion combined with the a hashmap.

Comment: I added the information about the extra Map to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend building your own structure to manage this as it adds flexibility (and speed) for your use case in particular.

I'd go with a circular queue to store each LIFO queue (stack). A circular queue is one where you add elements to the tail, and read (but doesn't remove) from the head. Once head = tail, you start over.

You can build your own queue using a simple array. It's not too hard to manage the synchronization around operations such as adding more queues to the array - and expanding it when needed. I believe adding queues to the array is not something you do very often.

This is easy to manage and you can expand your circular queue to calculate how often the entries are being accessed, and throttle the frequency of access to its entries (by adding/removing consumer threads, or even making them wait a bit before consuming from the stack managed by an entry).

You can even avoid thread locking when reading elements from the circular queue using multiple threads, by making them call a "register" operation before consuming from the stack: each thread has its ID and when it "registers" the ID is stored at the given queue entry. Before registering and before popping from the stack, the thread does a "read the registration ID" operation, and the ID that returns must match its own ID. That means only the thread that "owns" the given queue entry can pop from that stack. If the registration/confirmation of registration process fails, it means another thread is consuming form that entry, so the current thread moves on to the next available entry.

I've used this sort of strategy in the past and it scaled like a charm. I hope this makes sense for you.